# Concatenate string into a symbol using C Macros

Tags: c, string, macros

I have these arrays:

```
unsigned long SMDATA_0_SIZE=60;
unsigned long SMDATA_0[SMDATA_SIZE] = {
   <data>
};
unsigned long SMDATA_1_SIZE=60;
unsigned long SMDATA_1[SMDATA_1_SIZE] = {
   <data>
};
unsigned long LGDATA_0_SIZE=60;
unsigned long LGDATA_0[SMDATA_SIZE] = {
   <data>
};
unsigned long LGDATA_1_SIZE=60;
unsigned long LGDATA_1[SMDATA_1_SIZE] = {
   <data>
};
```

Which I'm attempting to pass as an argument to a function. Let's say `fmemopen` depending on a define:

```
#ifndef STRCONCAT
#define STRCONCAT(STR1,STR2) STR1 ## STR2
#endif
#ifdef SMALL_DATA
#define DATA_STR SMDATA
#endif
#ifdef LARGE_DATA
#define DATA_STR LGDATA
#endif
...
FILE* fd0 = fmemopen(STRCONCAT(DATA_STR,"_0"), strconcat(DATA_STR,"_0_SIZE"), "r");
FILE* fd1 = fmemopen(STRCONCAT(DATA_STR,"_1"), strconcat(DATA_STR,"_1_SIZE"), "r");
```

Yields:

```bash
myapp.c:164:26: error: pasting formed '"DATA_STR""\"_0\""', an invalid preprocessing token
      fd0 = fmemopen(STRCONCAT(DATA_STR,"_0"), STRCONCAT(DATA_STR,"_0_SIZE"), "r");
```

Trying:

```
FILE* fd0 = fmemopen(STRCONCAT(DATA_STR,_0), strconcat(DATA_STR,_0_SIZE), "r");
FILE* fd1 = fmemopen(STRCONCAT(DATA_STR,_1), strconcat(DATA_STR,_1_SIZE), "r");
```

Also did not work:

```bash
myapp.c:164:26: error: pasting formed '"DATA_STR""_0"', an invalid preprocessing token
      fd0 = fmemopen(STRCONCAT(DATA_STR,_0), STRCONCAT(DATA_STR,_0_SIZE), "r");
```

How would I change this to form the literal variable?

Comment: What part of it would be C++? Or do you think my compiler (I'm calling clang) is interpreting it as C++?

Comment: Your code shows a definition for `STRCONCAT` and invocations for `strconcat`, but your error messages show invocations for `STRCONCAT`. When asking Stack Overflow these sorts of questions, always prepare an isolated [mre] and make sure it and the error messages are consistent.

Comment: Gotcha. Good catch. I typed out the example as I didn't want to paste my code. Missed that.

Comment: If your expected result is a string literal you shouldn't use `##` to begin with but let the preprocessor use string literal concatenation. `"hello" "_0"` already gets pre-processed into `"hello_0"`.

Answer (score 2):

To paste `_0` or `_0_SIZE` to something, pass the macro `_0` or `_0_SIZE`, not `"_0"` or `"_0_SIZE"`. The `##` operator is a paste operator, not a remove-quotation-marks-and-then-paste operator.

To paste what `DATA_STR` expands to, insert another macro so the expansion is performed before the pasting. Change:

```
#define STRCONCAT(STR1,STR2) STR1 ## STR2
```

to:

```
#define Auxiliary(STR1,STR2) STR1 ## STR2
#define STRCONCAT(STR1,STR2) Auxiliary(STR1, STR2)
```

To use the `STRCONCAT` macro, use `STRCONCAT`, not `strconcat`.